How to create a dropdown Django admin filter with select2?
I am working on a Django admin customization where I need to create dropdown filters with select2. I am using the django-admin-autocomplete-filter package, which works fine for foreign keys but it seems regular fields are not supported. For example, my  Collection model has an IntegerField (months). I added list_filter = [AutocompleteFactory(‘Months’, ‘months’] inside the CollectionAdmin and I get this error: DeferredAttribute object had now attributed ‘get_queryset’

No, probably "DeferredAttribute object has no attribute ‘get_queryset’`".
